# Tensorflow AVX Support

Tags: performance, tensorflow, machine-learning, google-compute-engine, avx

Does anyone know if the Tensorflow compiled executables [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/get_started/os_setup.html#pip-installation) include AVX support? I have been running that compiled version of Tensorflow on Google Compute Engine and it is slow. Dog slow. Cold molasses slow. LA traffic slow. [This article](https://github.com/jasonmayes/Tensor-Flow-on-Google-Compute-Engine) says compiling with AVX support significantly improves performance on Google Compute Engine, but when I follow the compile process on that site it fails. Just wondering if AVX is already in the executables?

Comment: Disassemble it with something like `objdump -d` and look for `%ymm`.  If you ever see that string as part of a register name, the code is using AVX.  (Intel-syntax doesn't use `%` prefixes to separate register names from symbol names, so just look for ymm0 through ymm15).  Of course, that won't detect AVX 128 bit instructions like `vmulps %xmm0, %xmm1, %xmm2`, so you could also look for `vmulps`.  The leading `v` and (usually) 3 operands means it's an AVX instruction instead of legacy SSE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, tensorflow default distributions are built [without CPU extensions](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7778), such as SSE4.1, SSE4.2, AVX, AVX2, FMA, etc, because these builds (e.g. ones from `pip install tensorflow`) are intended to be compatible with as many CPUs as possible. Another argument is that even with these extensions CPU is a lot slower than a GPU, and it's expected for medium- and large-scale machine-learning training to be performed on a GPU. See also a [related discussion here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47068709/712995).

The article is right, AVX and FMA instructions significantly (up to 300%!) speed up linear algebra computation, namely dot-product, matrix multiply, convolution, etc. If you want to utilize it, I'll have to pass through compiling tensorflow from sources, which is discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41293077/712995).

Answer (score 3):

This is the simplest method. Only one step.

It's easy and has significant impact on speed. Can make training 3 times faster.

Refer
[custom builds of tensorflow](https://github.com/lakshayg/tensorflow-build)